# Integration services end-user interface from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssis

Is there an application or a way to configuring a sql server integration services from a end-user interface?

I need to give to my user a way to configuring a connection source, a connection destination and do many business rules.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built-in that does this.

Connections such as Source and Destination, as well as many other package parameters, can be configured with a .config file.   You could write a GUI that creates/edits .config files, which are just text (xml) files.

Any "business rules" that are more complex or cannot be accessed through a .config file, however, are not going to be so easy to allow your end-users to configure.